# RxSwift Cannot convert call result type '(_) -> Disposable' to expected type '(_) ->

Tags: uicollectionview, rx-swift, uicollectionreusableview, rx-cocoa, rxdatasources

I'm trying to add an headerView to a collectionView using RxSwift.

I get this error:

> Cannot convert call result type '(*) -> Disposable' to expected type '(*) ->

at this line:

```
obsHeader.asObservable().bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I don't understand how to fix it. Any help?

I post here the rest of the code:

```
struct SectionItemObject {
    let collectionViewRecommendations: UICollectionView
    let items: [SFCardViewModelListOfCardsProtocol]
}

struct SectionOfItems {
    var items: [Item]
}

extension SectionOfItems: SectionModelType {

    typealias Item = SectionItemObject

    init(original: SectionOfItems, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }

    init(items: [Item]?) {
        self.items = items ?? [Item]()
    }
}
```

And this is what I write in the method I call to observe.

```
let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionOfItems>(configureCell: { (datasource, collectionview, indexPath, i) -> UICollectionViewCell in
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardView", for: indexPath) as! CardView
        //                self.setCell(card:card,cell:cell)
        cell.lbTitle.text = "TEST"
        return cell
    }, configureSupplementaryView: { (datasource, collectionview, kind, indexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView in
        let section = collectionview.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "AddNewCardCollectionHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! AddNewCardCollectionHeaderView
        section.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        section.collectionViewRecommendations = self.collectionViewRecommendations
        return section
    } )

let item = SectionItemObject(collectionViewRecommendations: self.collectionViewRecommendations!, items: viewModelProtocol.searchedCards.value)
let obsHeader = Variable(SectionOfItems(items: [item]))

obsHeader.asObservable().bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I tried to compile your code, in my case it complains not about the line you mentioned but about "dataSource" declaration ("Argument passed to call that takes no parameters").

Comment: I edited the code copying exactly what I'm compiling. Can you check now? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that your `obsHeader` needs to be typed as `Variable<[SectionOfItems]>`

So just make it

```
let obsHeader = Variable([SectionOfItems(items: [item])])
```

Comment: Thanks! yes it was that!